# Using sessions to transport a variable over multiple pages

Tags: php, session

I want to make a transition page, to forward "URL" to. I have this code. Self explanatory. !var means that some var is not given. URL is some url like http://domain.com

```
session_start();
if (!$some_variable) {
  $data = "http://localhost/";
  $_SESSION['keks'] = $data;
  require("transition.php");
  exit();
}
```

transition.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Frameset</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
  <frame src="above.php" name="Navigation">
  <frame src="http://www.domain.com" name="Daten">
  <noframes>
    <body>
      <p>Something</p>
    </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

above.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['keks']; ?>">Continue</a> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which leads to

```
<a href="">
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Firstly, what is `!var`? Secondly, where is the `URL` constant defined?

Comment: @Treffynnon main post updated

Comment: You still havent shown where the variable `URL` is defined

Comment: @RichartBremer Post your actual code rather than this weird pseudo PHP.

Comment: @ManseUK Answer the question instead

Comment: Do all your PHP pages include the code that calls session_start()?

Comment: @belgther Looking at what was included above, no - see my answer below... Because this is using frames, session_start() must be included in above.php

Comment: belgther, thanks, that is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to give full code and not use `!var` - just put in the correct variable here as it is less confusing. Secondly you don't have any session in above.php

Unknown file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['keks'])) {
    //header("Location: ".URL, true, 301);
    $_SESSION['keks'] = "http://localhost/";
    require("transition.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

above.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['keks']; ?>">Continue</a> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['keks'])) {
   $data = 'URL';
   $_SESSION['keks'] = $data;
   require("transition.php");
   exit();
}
```

Also in above.php you need

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

To get the variable.

Comment: Surely it won't work as the 'above.php' is included in a frame - how does the `session` get into above.php if it isn't started on that page - frames are a bad idea...

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: keks in unknownFile.php on line <pointing to if (!$_SESSION['keks'])> if I use (@!$_SESSION['keks']), it works as previously, meaning <a href="">

Comment: Right, you better use `!isset($_SESSION['keks'])` to avoid this warning.